# ibatis.net or nhibernate on mono

Tags: nhibernate, mono, ibatis.net

I need a stable orm or dataccess framework to use with mono 2.4.2.3. Does anyone used ibatis.net (3.0 alpha or older) or nhibernate 2.1 on mono, are they solid enough for production use ?

Regards,
sirmak

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used IBatis but I have used NHibernate and have had no problems with it at all.

I am still running against mono 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

Our parent corporation has a framework that uses iBatis for the ORM stuff. They chose it because our corp's  enterprisey server stuff is about evenly divided between java and .net.